# Two-way contingency table in R

Tags: r, two-way, contingency

I have a dataframe and I want to output a two-way contingency table from two of the columns. They both have values "Too Little", "About Right" or "Too Much".

I'm typing

```
df %>%
  filter(!is.na(col1)) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

for both of them separately and get something like this:

```
col1        count
<fctr>      <int>
Too Little  19259           
About Right 9539            
Too Much    2816
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
       Too Little   About Right   Too Much   Total
col1   19259        9539          2816       31614
col2   20619        9374          2262       32255
Total  39878       18913          5078       63869
```

I've been trying to use table function

```
addmargins(table(df$col1, df$col2))
```

But the result is not what I want

```
              Too Little About Right Too Much   Sum
  Too Little       13770        4424      740 18934
  About Right       4901        3706      700  9307
  Too Much          1250         800      679  2729
  Sum              19921        8930     2119 30970
```

Comment: so what is the expected out put you want

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, it's important to ask questions in a [mimimal but complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) form. Also always try to include some example data (as of right now no one but you can see `df`) maybe just a few rows would suffice for a minimal example

Answer (score 3):

I'd give `tabulate` a try, which is the foundation for `table` (see `?tabulate`). For example given

```
set.seed(123)
vals <- LETTERS[1:3]
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(3, sample(vals, 5, T)))
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, "levels<-", vals))
```

then you could do

```
m <- t(sapply(df, tabulate, nbins = length(vals)))
colnames(m) <- vals
addmargins(m)
#     A B C Sum
# V1  1 1 3   5
# V2  1 3 1   5
# V3  1 2 2   5
# Sum 3 6 6  15
```

Or (via @thelatemail) just

```
addmargins(t(sapply(df, table)))
#     A B C Sum
# V1  1 1 3   5
# V2  1 3 1   5
# V3  1 2 2   5
# Sum 3 6 6  15
```

Comment: I don't know why you need `tabulate` specifically. Just `addmargins(t(sapply(df, table))` will do it and will retain the names.

Comment: @thelatemail true, thanks. I added this. (Although it may be too similar to zx8754's solution, now...)

Comment: nah, doing `sapply` is simpler than rbind-ing a list.

Comment: @thelatemail added benchmaring to my post, lukeA's solution takes the cake, 20x faster.

Answer (score 2):

We can use table in a loop then rbind:

```
# Using dummy data from @lukeA's answer

addmargins(do.call(rbind, lapply(df1, table)))
#     A B C Sum
# V1  1 1 3   5
# V2  1 3 1   5
# V3  1 2 2   5
# Sum 3 6 6  15
```

---

**Benchmarking**

```
# bigger data
set.seed(123)
vals <- LETTERS[1:20]
df1 <- as.data.frame(replicate(20, sample(vals, 100000, T)))
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(df1, "levels<-", vals))


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  lukeA = {
    m1 <- t(sapply(df1, tabulate, nbins = length(vals)))
    colnames(m1) <- vals
    m1 <- addmargins(m1)
  },
  # as vals only used for luke's solution, keep it in.
  lukeA_1 = {
    vals <- LETTERS[1:20]
    m2 <- t(sapply(df1, tabulate, nbins = length(vals)))
    colnames(m2) <- vals
    m2 <- addmargins(m2)
  },
  thelatemail = {m3 <- addmargins(t(sapply(df1, table)))}, 
  zx8754 = {m4 <- addmargins(do.call(rbind, lapply(df1, table)))}
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
#       lukeA  2.349969  2.371922  2.518447  2.473839  2.558653   3.363738   100
#     lukeA_1  2.351680  2.377196  2.523473  2.473839  2.542831   3.459242   100
# thelatemail 38.316506 42.054136 43.785777 42.674912 44.234193  90.287809   100
#      zx8754 38.695101 41.979728 44.933602 42.762006 44.244314 110.834292   100
```

Comment: It's definitely quicker regardless, but your benchmark leaves out the fact that `vals` isn't always known ahead of time (or at least shouldn't be assumed to be known). So you'd have to chuck a `vals <- unique(df1[,1)` in there as well.

Comment: @thelatemail True, maybe it even should be `vals <- unique(unlist(df1))`, but from OP's example, they know the values beforehand.